I [could beat]/[could have beaten] all of you
John's friends are playing tennis. John, whose right arm is in plaster, approaches them. They stop playing and turn to look at him and his broken arm. In the first scenario, in which he's going to play, he says sentence #1 to them:
1. Don't look at me like that! I'm going to play left-handed. If I hadn't fallen off my bike yesterday and hadn't broken my right arm, I [could beat]/[could have beaten] all of you.
And in the second scenario, in which he's not going to play, he says sentence #2:
2. Don't look at me like that! I'll hang out with you guys and watch you play, but I'm not going to play myself. Anyway, if I hadn't fallen off my bike yesterday and hadn't broken my right arm, I [could beat]/[could have beaten] all of you.
In both cases, the game is in the future. Is whether he's going to play or not relevant to the choice of tense? Which tense is correct in the above two scenarios? Thank you.

could have beaten is for games in the past, both played and not played

If I hadn't fallen off my bike = past conditional.

Consider that in context, the meaning of the counterfactual in John’s utterance is essentially the same as that of If my arm were not broken. And though it’s an irrealis, the time to which it refers is right now, at this moment. So in that alternate universe, his ability to beat all of them is prospective, not retrospective. It’s not really different from If I wished to play [and my arm were healthy], I could beat all of you.

I'll offer a counter-example. The friends are gathering for a planned tennis match at 10:00, but when John arrives with a broken arm, it's clear they can't have their doubles match and they decide to call off the game and all go home. As they leave, John says "It's okay, I would have won anyway."
Even though it's 10:05, or maybe even 9:55 when he says this, and the hypothetical match would still be in progress, the past tense can work here because the opportunity for the match has passed. But in your example, in which a game is still going forward, it doesn't fit.
